# HTTP Error code: 429 while accessing twitter premium API

Tags: python, twitter, http-status-code-429

How do I avoid being rate limited on twitter premium API? I can get a new endpoint but, how do I avoid making that mistake. I need to pull a lot of tweets from a lot of days. I have even tried the same endpoint after 5 hours, still getting the same error.

```
   from searchtweets import collect_results,ResultStream, gen_rule_payload, load_credentials
   import csv
   premium_search_args = load_credentials("E:\\residency_5\\practicum\\twitter_keys.yaml",yaml_key="search_tweets_premium",env_overwrite=False)

   rule = gen_rule_payload("#whistlepodu", to_date="2018-04-07",from_date="2018-04-08", results_per_call=100)
   print(rule)

   tweets = collect_results(rule,
                     max_results=5,
                     result_stream_args=premium_search_args)
   csvFile = open('E:\\residency_5\\practicum\\whistlepodu\\2.csv', 'a')

   csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

   for tweet in tweets:
       csvWriter.writerow([str(tweet.created_at_datetime), tweet.all_text.encode('utf-8'),tweet.hashtags,tweet.favorite_count,tweet.retweet_count])

   csvFile.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 retrying request; current status code: 429
 retrying request; current status code: 429
 retrying request; current status code: 429
 HTTP Error code: 429: Request exceeds account’s current query limits. Please upgrade to the next package level and retry.
 Rule payload: {'query': '#whistlepodu', 'maxResults': 100, 'toDate': '201804070000', 'fromDate': '201804080000'}
```

Any advice or tip is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/guides/response-codes.html as you see here these error codes mean that you reached TOO_MANY_REQUESTS or TWEET_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED.

Comment: Thanks for your time :). Can you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: As error message says "Please upgrade to the next package level and retry." either you can make queue and do requests with twitter API limits, (just make delay) or you can make few API accounts and make simple scrtipt that evenly chooses account.

Comment: I am getting that error even for 1 request (1 tweet per request), even after trying for several hours. Do I need to change some code to stay in limits.

Comment: Try to ask tech support of twitter about that, I think it's not normal. https://twittercommunity.com/

Comment: I found out the problem, it turns out we can only have 50 requests per month in full archive in twitter premium API and I have exhausted mine. Thanks for helping me out.